# Meaning of sample points in nonuniform discrete Fourier transform

Tags: fourier-series, fourier-transform

The [nonumiform discrete Fourier transform](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Non-uniform_discrete_Fourier_transform) is defined by the following formula:
$${\displaystyle X_{k}=\sum _{n=0}^{N-1}x_{n}e^{-2\pi ip_{k}\omega _{n}},\quad 0\leq k\leq N-1,}$$
where $p_0,...p_{N-1}\in[0,1]$ are so called sample points and ${\displaystyle \omega _{0},\ldots ,\omega _{N-1}\in [0,N]}$ are frequencies.

I now want to use the formula to calculate the Fourier series at so called *nonequispaced points*. That means, my points have a variable space between each other. An example:
[image: demonstrating graph]

There exist three types of nonuniform discrete Fourier transforms. For my use case, the second type (NUDFT-II) seems to fit the best, which uses uniform frequencies with $\omega_n = n$ and nonuniform sample points $p_k$, as it evaluates "a Fourier series at nonequispaced points" ([Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Non-uniform_discrete_Fourier_transform)).

I could, however, not find any explanation regarding how to choose the sample points $p_k$, or what those points actually stand for.

In the discrete Fourier transform $p_k$ equals $n/N$. Does this mean, that in the nonuniform discrete Fourier trasnform of type II it equals the distance of the current point $n$ to the beginning of the original signal divided by the length of the signal, hence describing "the percent of the time we've gone through" (as described [here](https://betterexplained.com/articles/an-interactive-guide-to-the-fourier-transform/))?

**Edit:** This theory is backed by [this](http://homepages.inf.ed.ac.uk/rbf/CVonline/LOCAL_COPIES/PIRODDI1/NUFT/node4.html) definition:
$$P(m) = \sum _{n=0}^{N-1}p_ne^{-j\frac{2\pi}{T}mt_n}$$
Which can be translated to use the same variable names:
$$X_k = \sum _{n=0}^{N-1}x_ne^{-2\pi i\frac{t_n}{T}k}$$

Hence $p_k$ would equal $\frac{t_n}{T}$ and $\omega$ would equal $k$. This however is a little bit weird, as the Wikipedia article stated that $\omega$ should equal $n$. Is this a mistake of the Wikipedia article? Actually I think it makes much more sense with $k$. But can I assume that my assumption was right and $p_k$ does equal $\frac{t_n}{T}$?

However, this causes another problem: For which frequencies does the transform has to be applied? With the normal Fourier transform it's generally from $0$ up to $N-1$. This doesn't seem to work here though. Do I now have to calculate the values for the frequencies from $t_0$ to $t_{N-1}$?

Comment: After all this time, did you find the answer?

Comment: @JFonseca nope, I gave up on it

Comment: @JFonseca   RE: uniform sample points.